# docker container wont run apache2 virtual host

Tags: docker, apache, virtualhost

I'm learning docker.. I build the docker image, consisting apache2 over an ubuntu base, then I create my apache virtual host directory and load my index.html and [virtual host].conf, reload apache config.

The build process completes without error and I can see the new image in my local docker repo. I can create a container from it and see it running in a browser via docker host ip:port. Then as expected, when I stop the container the browser cannot find the website.

Two problems however:

1. The browser only shows the default Apache 'It works!' web page; not my virtual host.
2. When I try to view the docker container logs to figure out root cause, I see my docker was installed (into my lubuntu VM) as root, thus (I think), preventing me from accessing the docker container / log folders. I don't know the root password and regardless, understood the lubuntu VM image's root user to not have a password?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
LABEL maintainer="contact@devopscube.com"
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install apache2 -y 
RUN mkdir /var/www/html/tutorialDocker
COPY /src_files/tutorialDocker.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/tutorialDocker.conf
COPY /src_files/index.html /var/www/html/tutorialDocker/index.html
EXPOSE 80
RUN a2ensite tutorialDocker.conf
RUN apache2ctl -k graceful
CMD apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: 1) Isn't there a setting in the actual apache .conf file (not your virtual host) that tells it to load other virtual host config files). 2) Make a user within your Dockerfile, for example `www-data` give it the same `uid` as your own user on your own machine. Default is 1000. then `chown -R www-data:www-data your-directory`

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately that didn't get me closer to figuring out why the virtual host doesn't work. thanks anyway.

Comment: There's a project on github called `laradock` it has a Dockerfile for Apache: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/apache2/Dockerfile it relies heavily on a .env file, but maybe you can learn from it

Comment: Thanks for the info, UnderDog. 

After following the httpd base docker image documentation, I finally was able to get it to work rather aimply with two statements, i.e.

FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./src_files/index.html /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/

Thanks for your help!